# Why do I have to state module name to create object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a module which defines a class as follows:

```
class PyTimeCode(object):
   <methods, etc.>
```

In the python interpreter, I do the following:

```
import pytimecode

mytc = PyTimeCode(6)
```

The above does not work (generates a `NameError`).

The following works:

```
import pytimecode

mytc = pytimecode.PyTimeCode(6)
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how the [`import`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement works. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> The first form of import statement binds the module name in the local namespace to the module object, and then goes on to import the next identifier, if any. If the module name is followed by as, the name following as is used as the local name for the module.

If you want to use module contents without prefixing use the [`from`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#from) form:

> The from form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus found

An example regarding your code:

```
from pytimecode import PyTimeCode

mytc = PyTimeCode(6)
```

or (in general not recommended):

```
from pytimecode import *

mytc = PyTimeCode(6)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks so much, will accept as soon as SO lets me.  One follow up question: For some reason, when I do `pip freeze`, this module shows up with the name `pytimecode.py` while the `.py` extension is not shown for the other module names.  Is this important?  Would it have an effect on anything?  Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu Sorry, no idea. But perhaps just ask another question, probably someone who knows `pip` will help you.